# My MacBook's battery drains when I don't use it

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

It has been noticed a few times that (for example) I worked with [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) and some other apps, and then I left my MacBook with 80 percent of the battery. After a few minutes it automatically goes sleep, *but* in the morning when I try to wake it up I see that it has 0 percent of battery... Why is it happening? Shouldn't it just stop all the background processes and save the battery if I don't use it?

It is a pretty new MacBook. System battery info:

[image]

**UPD**

added log file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11SPeV5BujYymF5RajAOSDvS0xsToy3sX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you leave it asleep during the day, how long does it last?

Comment: @2br-2b The last time I left it was around 22:00 and in the morning 7:00 it was out of battery

Comment: What about during the day? How long does it last over a typical day?

Comment: @2br-2b actually during the day it does well, let's say the full battery is enough for a few hours (doing a work). I also noticed that a few times (eg:) when I close the screen and put it in my back then I came to the office (±1 hour) and when I pull it back and open I feel it warm, looks like it doesn't sleep, but did some job while I commuting

Comment: What model is this (e.g. how old)? How many battery cycles are listed in System Information > Power? The older it is beyond 3 years old, the greater the likelihood that the battery needs replacing. Also, what OS version, and do you have Power Nap turned on?

Comment: @benwiggy added to the question

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Please amend your question with the portion of the output of the command `pmset -g log` that spans from shortly before you put the laptop to sleep to until shortly after you reboot it from 0% power. I suspect it's waking up constantly when it should be sleeping and I want to see the wake reasons and/or sleep assertions. (You can upload the text to a service like www.PasteBin.com since it will probably be lengthy.)

Comment: @pion put it here https://drive.google.com/file/d/11SPeV5BujYymF5RajAOSDvS0xsToy3sX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Can you tell me the date and approximate times to look for?

Comment: @pion last time it happened today night (currently it is 10:50 in my country), I left it with 80 percent of battery, and today when I got to the office I found out that it had no battery.

Comment: Conjecture: You have a bitcoin-mining virus.

Comment: Can you [add](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/424346/edit) the important information in comments to your question (as comments can be deleted at any time and an answer uses the information)?  But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.

Comment: @DJG is it suspicious or have you conclude it according to the log file or something else? Is there a way to make it sure?

Comment: @PeterMortensen added

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Have you performed both experiments that I suggested in my answer?

Comment: @pion still no, I'll do. I just have seen that according to the upvotes this question interested others, so I decided to start a bounty in order to draw attention may be your answer could help others too:)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Is this still an issue for you each night? If so, we should continue the investigation. The experiments I suggested may not resolve anything; they are just the logical next pieces of data that we need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you initiated sleep last night around 20:21.

> 2021-07-20 20:21:47 +0300 Sleep                   Entering Sleep state
> due to 'Software Sleep pid=133':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt
> (Charge:83%) 764 secs

At that point, your battery had 83% charge remaining. However, the sleep was specified to only last 764 seconds, or 12:44, and indeed the machine woke up exactly 12 minutes and 44 seconds later:

> 2021-07-20 20:34:31 +0300 Wake                    Wake from Deep Idle
> [CDNVA] : due to EC.PowerButton/User Using BATT (Charge:83%)

The system did not attempt to reenter sleep after that point. It then took only 13:24 more for your battery to lose 9% charge.

> 2021-07-20 20:47:55 +0300 Assertions              Summary- [System:
> SysAct] Using Batt(Charge: 74)

Less than three hours later, the system initiated a sleep due to low battery power because it had exhausted its reserve capacity:

> 2021-07-20 23:09:41 +0300 Sleep                   Entering Sleep state
> due to 'Low Power Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=inactive Using Batt (Charge:0%)
> 33177 secs

So you did not, in fact, slowly lose power overnight. Your laptop remained awake for several hours and then entered emergency sleep. It stayed sleeping until the morning when you attached AC and opened the lid:

> 2021-07-21 08:22:38 +0300 Wake                    Wake from Standby
> [CDNVA] : due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open Using AC (Charge:0%)

Now, the initial wakeup at 20:34:31 would be normal (it is a maintenance wake, i.e., 'Power nap') but the wake reason is not what I'd expect (`EC.PowerButton/User`  rather than `EC.RTC/Maintenance`). This may be a bug.

That, alone, does not explain why your machine never went to sleep afterwards. What I can observe is that, after it wakes up, every minute or two it creates and releases a sleep assertion. I'm having trouble following the pairs, but there is likely a running process that's preventing sleep. (For example, I saw many instances of audio playback doing this in your log. Did you have music/videos playing in Chrome?)

1. A crude but easy way to start attacking this is to quit all your apps before putting the machine to sleep for the night.
2. As a separate experiment (do this before OR after experiment 1, not during), disable Power Nap.

In both cases, if the problem persists, please upload a new log (and specify the exact start + stop dates & times).